Who is the "other one" in Daniel 7?
Is there any interpretation that makes sense of the passage in Daniel 7 (quoted below):
According to Rashi the "other one" who will arise is Titus, but that would mean that Mashiach had to arrive right afterwards. According to Rambam it is Mohammed, but it does not really fit with 10 Kings. Is there any explanation that sits well?
The fourth beast [means]—there will be a fourth kingdom upon the earth which will be different from all the kingdoms; it will devour the whole earth, tread it down, and crush it.
And the ten horns [mean]—from that kingdom, ten kings will arise, and after them another will arise. He will be different from the former ones, and will bring low three kings.
He will speak words against the Most High, and will harass the holy ones of the Most High. He will think of changing times and laws, and they will be delivered into his power for a time, times, and half a time.

I don't understand the question. This is a prophecy regarding end-times. Are you asking how this specific detail came to pass? It's not apparent that this already came to pass (as is evident by the fact that both Rashi and Rambam identify this passage with different figures and events separated by several centuries.

This answer is partially about your quote from the Book of Daniel, a portion  of Ketuvim, Writings, and partially to the status of Daniel as a prophet.
What follows is excerpted from Rabbi Steinsaltz introduction to the Book of Daniel as hosted on Sefaria. Rabbi Steinsaltz differentiates those people acknowledged as Nevi'im, true prophets, and those who are not. In his opinion, Daniel was not a Prophet, and the Book of Daniel is not prophecy.
Rabbi Steinsaltz defines a prophet is "a person who receives his words as a prophecy and delivers them as a messenger of G-d." Not everyone who has visions is speaking words originating directly from G-d. Many non-Jews attempt to find origins and predictions of their own religions by misinterpreting Jewish seforim through their own religious beliefs. They do this through ignorance of the original or through malicious manipulation. By claiming their interpretation as being "correct" their purpose is the conversion of Jews away from Judaism and toward their religion.
Specific to Daniel 7, Rabbi Steinsaltz writes:

(Daniel 7:1–28)
The Four Kingdoms and the Kingdom That Follows Them
In this vision, which Daniel receives in a dream, he sees large animals and other figures. An angel deciphers the dream’s main
message, which relates to various kingdoms that will arise and fall
from the stage of history in the future. Despite the angel’s
assistance, the meaning of many of the details noticed by Daniel
remain obscure.

The status of Daniel as a prophet:

The book of Daniel is unique among the books of the Bible in several respects.

The book of Daniel focuses on one central character. While other individuals appear in the book as well, it mainly relates the story of
Daniel’s life, from his early years, and describes his deeds and
visions.

Despite Daniel’s visions, he is not considered a full-fledged prophet. The fact that the book of Daniel is not listed among the
books of Prophets in the Bible, but rather as part of the Writings, is
not because of its relatively late date.


Rather, Daniel is not one of the books of the Prophets because Daniel has a different status from the prophets whose books were included in that section of the Bible.  A prophet is not simply one
who sees heavenly visions, predicts the future, or discloses events
occurring in other parts of the world, but a person who receives his
words as a prophecy and delivers them as a messenger of G-d.
Even when [Daniel] dealt with general matters and shared the revelations he had experienced through angels or by means of dreams,
he was not sent to others as a prophet. Consequently, his book can be described as a biography.


This does not answer the question. That Daniel wasn’t a “prophet” in the traditional sense is an explicit gemara (Megillah 3a).

@Yø-cRo the question was "Is there any Interpretation that makes sense of the passage in Daniel 7 (quoted below)". I think Rabbi Steinsaltz's interpretation makes perfect sense, especially given the status of Daniel's dreams not being prophesy.

“The meaning is obscure” is not an explanation. Additionally, I think you may be misunderstanding what the Gemara (and Rabbi Steinzaltz) mean when they say Daniel is not considered a prophet. They mean that we only call someone a prophet when he was sent to convey a message; not that Daniel’s visions weren’t true prophecy - it was just a personal prophecy.
